# Process Synchronization in C

Tags: c, process, signals, fork, signal-handling

I am trying to develop a 3 player game in C. The program creates a 3 child and 1 parent. Parent prints and go to sleep and sends signal to related child. Child pauses after some calculations and parent should wake up again. But the output is nowhere closer to it. I tried using sleep() at various places but no luck. Can someone please help me out

```
void action(){}
void child(char *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid1,pid2, pid3;
    printf("This is a 3 player game\n");
    if((pid1=fork()==0)) child("TOTO");
    if((pid2=fork()==0)) child("TITI");
    if((pid3=fork()==0)) child("TUTU");

   sleep(1);
   signal(SIGUSR1, action);
   while(1)
   {
       printf("\nRefree: TOTO Plays\n\n");
       kill(pid1,SIGUSR1);
       pause();
       printf("\nRefree: TITI Plays\n\n");
       kill(pid2,SIGUSR1);
       pause();
       printf("\nRefree: TUTU Plays\n\n");
       kill(pid3, SIGUSR1);
       pause();
   }
}
void child(char *s)
{
   int points=0,dice;
   while(1)
   {
       signal(SIGUSR1, action);
       pause();
       printf("\n%s: Playing my dice\n",s);
       dice = (rand() % 10)+1;
       printf("%s: got %d points\n",s, dice);
       points+=dice;
       printf("%s: Total so far %d\n\n", s, points);
       sleep(2);
       if(points >= 50)
       {
           printf("%s: game over I won\n", s);
           kill(0, SIGTERM);
       }
       kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
   }
}
```

Output I get is

```
This is a 3 player game

Refree: TOTO Plays




TITI: Playing my dice
TUTU: Playing my dice
TOTO: Playing my dice
TUTU: got 4 points
TOTO: got 4 points
TOTO: Total so far 4

TITI: got 4 points
TUTU: Total so far 4

TITI: Total so far 4

User defined signal 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parentheses are misplaced.  You wrote:

```
if((pid1=fork()==0)) child("TOTO");
```

It should be:

```
if((pid1=fork())==0) child("TOTO");
```

What happens in your case is that you assign 0 to `pid1`, `pid2`, and `pid3` in the parent process, and 1 in the child processes because `fork()==0` is evaluated before the assignment operator `=`.

I would recommend not using operations with side effects inside expressions (although I know it is common practice in cases like this).  After all, if you had spent one more line, you could have avoided the issue altogether:

```
pid1 = fork();
if (pid1 == 0) child("TOTO");
```

Operations with side effects such as `=`, `+=`, `*=`, `++`, `--`, etc. are safest when used as separate statements.  Inside other expressions, their meaning can be unclear or even undefined.  In the following statement:

```
x = x++ + 1;
```

the increment `++` may be applied before `=` is evaluated or afterwards.  If `x = 0` initially, `x` may be 1 or 2 afterwards.

Comment: Good catch with the `x++` .. this actually means that the code leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
pid1=fork()==0
```

This is nasty, but what you're actually doing here is this:

```
pid1 = (fork() == 0)
```

Operator `==` has a [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than operator `=`.

If you want your game to be *fun* though note that you should probably seed your random numbers, otherwise it's ... kind of boring ;)

You can seed the random numbers with `srand(time(NULL));`

Also, as general advice: Check *every* system call (like `fork`) as well as *every* library function (`malloc`) that could fail for errors. Moreover, the use of `signal` is [not recommended](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal).

Comment: Thanks. I see that this was a silly mistake. I took your advice to not use signals and now I am gonna try same thing using pipe() and dup() system calls to make parent wait till child is playing. This will make the program more efficient I guess.